# Problem with pendulum code cant get to plot Mathematica 11.3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I copied from an example about a pendulum. (A Mathematica Primer for Physicists, p38).   Can't get the `LogPlot` to work. Get just the axis. Using version 11.3 on Windows 10
[image]

```
 Remove["Global`*"]
 t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
 int = Integrate[
        1/Sqrt[Cos[θ] - Cos[θ0]], {θ, θ0, 0},
        Assumptions -> {θ0 > 0 && θ0 > Pi}];
t2 = AbsoluteTime[];
time = (t2 - t1)/60
period = -4 Sqrt[1/(2 g)] int
ratio = period/(2 Pi Sqrt[1/g]);
LogPlot[ratio, {θ0, 0, 0.99 Pi}]
```

Comment: The dark blue means the variable is undefined, and the light blue means the variable is used by the function in Mathematica (i.e. as the integration variable, or as the variable you are plotting). The function is not plotting for a few reasons. Some reasons include that `g` is never defined, the output of ratio is only defined for `theta0` in $(2\pi.3\pi)$ , and the output is complex in that region.

Comment: @Kuba. Thanks. However I copied this snippet faithfully from a notebook. Do you think that the book is wrong?

Comment: You need to change your assumptions on theta0 in your code to match your screenshot.  theta0 < Pi.

Comment: The suggestion of @BillWatts is enough to fix it for me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

As Bill Watts said in his comment, you need to make your assumptions agree with the ones made in your textbook, then everything works.

```
int = 
  Integrate[1/Sqrt[Cos[θ] - Cos[θ0]], {θ, θ0, 0}, Assumptions -> {0 <= θ0 < Pi}];
g = 9.8125;
period = -4 Sqrt[1/(2 g)] int;
ratio = period/(2 Pi Sqrt[1/g]);
LogPlot[ratio, {θ0, 0, 0.99 Pi}]
```

[image: plot]